# VBA, trying to find minimum and maximum value in a variant range? Getting 424 error

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use the code below to figure out min and max values in a range, but keep getting a 424 error Object required, does anyone know why?

```
Sub stochastic()
lr = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).row
x = 2
Dim rng As Variant
Dim minimum As Double
Dim maximum As Double

While x < lr
y = x + 13


Set rng = Data.Range("D" & x & ":" & "D" & y)
minimum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(rng)
maximum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(rng)
```

The error occurs at :::  Set rng = Data.Range("D" & x & ":" & "D" & y)  :::

Thanks!

Comment: Please format your code.. and what line causes the error? Did you debug it?

Comment: Hi, Im not sure what you mean by format. But the error occurs on :

Set rng = Data.Range("D" & x & ":" & "D" & y)

Im trying to look for alternative solutions, but cant find any.

Comment: shouldnt there be a `End Sub` and an `End While` statement somewhere? I don't know what `Data` is in your method. But maybe take a look at this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238%28v=office.15%29.aspx

Comment: @user3457548 I don't understand why the default is NOT to enforce the requirement to explicitly declare all variables. Please set that option Under Tools/Options Editor and place Option Explicit at the start of your macro. Had you done that, you would not have gotten that error as the fact that "Data" in the line giving you the error was not defined would have been flagged.  And you would have realized that was an illegal construct.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `Data.Range("D" & x & ":" & "D" & y)` you should use something like `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("D" & x & ":" & "D" & y)` - as @Stefan Falk pointed out, you haven't defined `Data`

Answer (score 0):

`While` should be terminated with `Wend` in VBA

```
Sub stochastic()
lr = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
x = 2
Dim rng As Variant
Dim minimum As Double
Dim maximum As Double

While x < lr
y = x + 13
    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("D" & x & ":" & "D" & y)
    minimum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(rng)
    maximum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(rng)
    'x=x+??
Wend
End Sub
```

This compiles - but `x` does not update in the loop (I've commented out the `x` update for you to fill in). Also, not sure if this is what you want your code to do, as you have not specified.

Using `variant` should be avoided, if possible. There are some cases where it is useful, but here you should be defining `dim rng as Range`.

Also the use of undefined types will (usually) be converted to `Variant` types. This means `y` will be variant. If you know the type, you should define it.